# How can I create a list and look up a value in C#

Tags: c#

I would like to implement some kind of a look up in C# but I am not sure how to do this.

I have a variable that can have a value of between 0 and 9. For each variable there will be a text string that goes with it.

I guess I need to set up some kind of list.

A really simple example on how I could access the list and how I could populate the list would be much appreciated.

I tried the following:

```
public static class RefData
{
    public static Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    dict.Add(0, "This Text");
    dict.Add(3, "That Text");
    dict.Add(4, "More Text");
}
```

but it gives an error message saying "can't resolve symbol dict on the lines with the dict.Add

Comment: I would just use a array aka `string[10]`

Comment: You can use enum too, if the text string values are the same everytime, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: The problem with the code you've posted in the question is that you're trying to execute statements directly within the class, instead of within a method / constructor / static constructor. As it happens, a collection initializer can help you in this case if you're using C# 3 - but you need to understand why it's failing at the moment.

Comment: @Jon - I am using C# 3. Are you saying that I can make it work by putting the code inside a constructor for the class RefData?

Comment: @kiyoshi Add the code inside a method you wont get that error

Comment: @Kiyoshi: Well if you're trying to initialize a *static* variable, you don't want to put it in an *instance* constructor. I've added two options in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an answer to the updated question. The problem with your current code is that you're trying to execute *statements* without them being inside a method, property, constructor etc. You can't do that. There are two obvious options here. First, you can use a method to build your dictionary:

```
public static class RefData
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<int, string> dict = BuildDictionary();

    private static Dictionary<int, string> BuildDictioary()
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> ret = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        ret.Add(0, "This Text");
        ret.Add(3, "That Text");
        ret.Add(4, "More Text");
        return ret;
    }
}
```

The other is to use a *collection initializer* if you're using C# 3 or higher:

```
public static class RefData
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<int, string> dict = 
        new Dictionary<int, string>
    {
        { 0, "This Text" },
        { 3, "That Text" },
        { 4, "More Text" }
    };
}
```

Note how in both cases I've made the variable private and read-only. You should almost *never* expose fields publicly - particularly mutable ones. You'll probably want to provide appropriate methods which *act* on the dictionary - and remember that `Dictionary` is *not* thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks very much. What would the method look like if I wanted to do a look up on the dictionary values. It would just be a public lookup?

Comment: @Kiyoshi: It would be a public method which used the dictionary as the other answers show. You'd have to decide what you wanted the behaviour to be if given key wasn't in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to put code inside of a class definition.  You need to move your dict.Add() calls either in a method or a static constructor.  Something like:

```
public static class RefData
{
    public static Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    static Refdata() //this could also be: public static void PopulateDictionary()
    {
        dict.Add(0, "This Text");
        dict.Add(3, "That Text");
        dict.Add(4, "More Text"); 
    }
}
```

You can do that if you want to fill it with default data, I suppose, you can always add or remove keys from it later from other parts of your code, since its a public static member.

---

A generic dictionary.  Something like:

```
 Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>()
```

The first type, int is your key.  Each key has to be unique, and will have a string value.

If you did something like this:

```
 dict.Add(0, "This Text");
 dict.Add(3, "That Text");
 dict.Add(4, "More Text");
```

you could look up the value like this:

```
 string value = dict[3];  //returns "That Text"
```

If a *key* already exists in the dictionary, the add will fail.  As in you can't do this twice:

```
 dict.Add(3, "That Text");
 dict.Add(3, "More Text");
```

As I said before, the key (in this case your int) has to be unique. You can reassign the value by doing

```
 dict[3] = "New Text"
```

The great thing about a generic dictionary, is that it can hold any type you want!  The definition of the dictionary is `Dictionary<Tkey, TValue>`, you get to specify the types, and you can set them to whatever you want.

Comment: Shouldn't we use byte instead of int, as the op has mentioned the values are only 0 through 9.I am not saying you are wrong, i am just asking whether I am wrong

Comment: Here's a great resource that expands upon the answer http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary

Comment: @Vamsi You can, I suppose.  There's nothing wrong with doing it that way.  If you want to save the space you can, but if you wind up going outside of the byte range, you'd have to change your declaration to a larger datatype.

Comment: @Christopher - I tried this but it gives an error. I am not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary class is your friend here.

e.g.

```
var textByNumber = new Dictionary<int, string>();    
textByNumber[0] = "Alice";    
textByNumber[1] = "Bob";
```

And to retrive a value, you can go:

```
var text = textByNumber[1];
```

Comment: You mean `Dictionary<int, string>` - the key type comes before the value type.

Comment: @Jon - I tried this but get an error message. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Dictionary` class in `System.Collections.Generic`

```
Dictionary<byte, string> dct = new Dictionary<byte, string>();
```

You can add values to the dictionary like this

```
dct.Add(0, "Some Value");
```

you can access the values in dictionary like this

```
string val = dct[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I have a variable that can have a value of between 0 and 9. For each variable there will be a text string that goes with it.
```

This means that you need a dictionary. You can use many specialized dictionaries in .NET. But my recommendation is to use:

```
Dictionary<int, string> list = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

To check if the list already contains something or not, simply use:

```
list.ContainsKey(someIntHere);
```

To get the string value of the specified key, simply use:

```
string value = list[key];
```